# JUNK at bottom of woocommerce shop page

Tags: woocommerce, navigation

My woocommerce page has junk at the bottom, under the products display.  I've copied the templates over and am modifying the archive-product.php file as per all the instructions, but I cannot find where the problem lies.  Under the products, I am getting a search bar, then a page nav, an post archive date list, and post categories.  It's ugly.

Has anyone ever experienced this and know how to fix it?  I could provide the code if necessary to look at.
Thanks,
Shawn

Comment: If the problem goes away when switching back to a default theme, then the problem is with your theme. If not the theme, then you want to try disabling other plugins and re-enabling them one by one until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the widgets section of the dashboard: Apearance -> Widgets (http://example.com/wp-admin/widgets.php) 
Check if those widgets are in the "Main Sidebar" or any of the other widget areas on that page and if they are remove them.